# WITH (CTE) table doesn't exist in mySQL

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression

I know there are a lot of similar questions on stackoverflow but none of them are equivalent.
I try to use a CTE but once I run it the error message: `Table 'food.test' doesn't exist` comes.
I have a database called `food` with tables like `vegetables`, `fruits` and some more.

```
WITH test AS (
  SELECT f.name
  FROM food.fruit f
  WHERE f.name != 'Apple' and f.name like 'A%'
)

SELECT *
FROM test
```

This is just an example. (I know in this case there's no need for an CTE)
How can I make sure that it finds my `test` table?

Thanks in advance

Comment: CTEs are available from version 8 what version are you on -select version()

Comment: Ahhh, thank you very much! I'm on version 5.7

Comment: MySQL version 5.7 **MUST** produce the next error message: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'test AS ( SELECT f.name FROM fruit f WHERE f.name != 'Apple' and f.name li' at line 1`. Your error message differs - hence either you use another DBMS/version or this error message is produced by client-side syntax checker.

Comment: I will gently point out here that MySQL 5.7 is going away soon, and the actual answer to your question is "use MySQL 8"